# PhantomJS and Selenium Webdriver - How to scrape next page table which is loaded by js

Tags: javascript, selenium

Everybody told me that i will get the table content generated by JS once I use PhantomJS. But i still fail.

I expected get the table on the website http://data.eastmoney.com/xg/xg/default.html

Page1 is ok.

When I use click() on css selector location of page2 to get page2, the content returned is still page1. What is the problem?

```
#coding:utf-8
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get("http://data.eastmoney.com/xg/xg/default.html")
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#PageCont > span.at").click()

list_cates = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#dt_1 > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(2) > a").text
print(list_cates)
```

Comment: It cannot take the content of table on page2 after click() action...
“list_cates = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#dt_1 > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(2) > a").text
print(list_cates)”

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is you are not waiting for the data to be updated after the click happens. You need to wait for sometime so that the Ajax call is complete

```
#coding:utf-8
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get("http://data.eastmoney.com/xg/xg/default.html")
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#PageCont .next").click()

time.sleep(5)
list_cates = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#dt_1 > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(2) > a").text
print(list_cates)
# Prints '太平鸟'
```

which matches the page 2 data

[image: Page 2]

Comment: Hi Tarun, really appreciated for you. 
And more question, i updated the codes to scrap data in 1st row on page 1-3. 
But always feedback wrong results which are existed on page 1 and last page.
OH...Where should I to post picture and code? I am freshman for stackoverflow....

Answer (score 0):

look at me Tarun Lalwani, codes and pics as below:

```
 #coding:utf-8
    from selenium import webdriver
    import time
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
    driver.get("http://data.eastmoney.com/xg/xg/default.html")
    time.sleep(2)
    for page_count in range(1,4):
        driver.find_element_by_id("gopage").send_keys(page_count)
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#PageCont > a.btn_link").click()
        time.sleep(10)
        list_cates = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#dt_1 > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(2) > a").text
        print('get' + str(page_count) + 'pcs')
        print(list_cates)
```

[run result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJfh3.png)

And in the other case, I want to get frame table by PhantomJS and also fail.

```
    #coding:utf-8
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get("http://ipo.csrc.gov.cn/checkClick.action?choice=info#")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#type1 > a").click()

time.sleep(5)
result = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#frame_body > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td:nth-child(1)").text
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I find the solution for the case 1 by added this code:driver.find_element_by_id("gopage").clear().

But the other case still need you help, many thanks!

```
#coding:utf-8
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get("http://data.eastmoney.com/xg/xg/default.html")
time.sleep(2)
for page_count in range(1,4):
    driver.find_element_by_id("gopage").clear()
    driver.find_element_by_id("gopage").send_keys(page_count)
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#PageCont > a.btn_link").click()
    time.sleep(5)
    list_cates = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#dt_1 > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(2) > a").text
    print('get' + str(page_count) + 'pcs')
    print(list_cates)
    driver.find_element_by_id("gopage").clear()
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for case 2 by added the code:driver.switch_to_frame("myframe")

Question need to be solved in frame structure!

Still very thanks to you for solving my problem. And this my first show in Stackoverflow, I love it!

```
#coding:utf-8
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get("http://ipo.csrc.gov.cn/checkClick.action?choice=info#")

time.sleep(2)
driver.switch_to_frame("myframe")
result = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#frame_body > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td:nth-child(1)").text
print(result)
```